# Bathroom Switch Wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I need some help with confirming the wiring in my bathroom so I can replace some of the switches. It's a double rocker with three main wires coming from the back of the box. It looks like they grouped the neutrals, grounds and then used the middle black wire to power the left and right. The left switch is for the ceiling fan and the right one is for the light switch. I'm not sure why they didn't connect the grounds to the switches, but any confirmation or help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to replace these switches with something that has "smarts", like a timer, sensor, or wifi/bluetooth/zwave "smart switcdh"?

Comment: They didn't connect grounds to switches because with a properly grounded metal box and metal switch yokes, switches are normally self-grounding.

Comment: That doesn't look like a metal box, so the grounds should have been connected to the switches and up to the fan and fixture.   Other than that, it's a very typical wiring pattern.

Comment: I agree with George that’s a plastic box.  I know some electricians that (in the past) did not connect switches if a plastic cover was used, the thinking was as in this case plastic box, plastic switch , plastic cover then there is no need for the ground. However the screw is the catch here and it can be the problem so they should be grounded. Since it appears all 4 wires are black at the switch  the hot coming in is black , switched then going out on black, the neutral should be good to use with smart switches.